# Функция load и браузеры

Tags: html, javascript

Вставляют внешний html в div при помощи load.

```
<script type="text/javascript">$('#menu2').load('menu2/menu2.html');</script>
```

Видит только IE, и то спрашивает разрешения на выполнение activX. Ни Опера, Гугл-хром ничего не видят - див остается просто пустым.

Answer (score 1):

Даю 100% гарантию, что у вас сей код не вызывается на событии **$(document).ready()**.
Попробуйте так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu2').load('menu2/menu2.html');
})
```

я прав? xD

Comment: Что в лоб, что по лбу... Где-то есть ошибка. 

В хедере - <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery-latest.js"></script>

в боди - 

<DIV id="Layer7" align="center"><BR>
<div id="menu2"></div>


<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu2').load('menu2.html');
}</script>

</DIV>
...........
плюс ко всему редактор стал просить потерянную ")"

Comment: Конечно, будет просить "ready(" не закрыто ")".